# How to prevent BottomsheetDialog from full screen

Tags: android

I have an custom BottomsheetDialog in my android(Kotlin) project. After swipe it expanded to ful screen. I can I prevent it from full screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code in onStart() :

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    // Prevent full-screen behavior
    dialog?.let { dialog ->
        dialog.window?.apply {
            setLayout(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                (resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels * 0.5).toInt()
            )
            setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM)
        }

        dialog.findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet).also {
            BottomSheetBehavior.from(it).apply {
                peekHeight = resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels / 2 // Set the peek height to half of the screen height
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).